# How to include a referenced assembly in a package?

Tags: c#, .net, nuget, assemblies

I have a project (A.csproj) which references an assembly (B.DLL) that is not part of the .NET framework.

Packing the project with `nuget pack a.csproj` effectively builds the package but when testing the package it doesn't contain the B.DLL and obviously it is not added as a reference.

I've tried to use `nuget spec` but nothing related to that reference could be found in the generated nuspec file.

I've also tried to use the [Create New NuGet Package From Project After Each Build 1.7.3](http://www.nuget.org/packages/CreateNewNuGetPackageFromProjectAfterEachBuild/1.7.3) package but it didn't help.

What are the steps needed for including and referencing an assembly in a NuGet package ?

Comment: Do you *need* to use `nuget pack` with your project file rather than creating a nuspec file?

Comment: @JonSkeet No it doesn't matter, any method is welcome. Actually I've tried both methods but with the same result.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

if you need fine-grained control over the layout and content of your NuGet package, then you should create a `nuspec` file and use that to create the package.  Then you can add files with the following syntax, for example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<package xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/packaging/2010/07/nuspec.xsd">
   <metadata schemaVersion="2">
     ...
   </metadata>
   <files>
     <file src="Foo.dll" target="lib\net45" />
     ...
   </files>
</package>
```

Comment: Okay great but one thing, it says "b.dll" not found unless I make it src="bin\Release\b.dll". Is this the right way to reference it (hard coding the bin\Release folder) ?

Comment: @Aybe There's no "right" answer, it's up to you based on your needs.  For my own project (from where this snippet came), I build everything outside of Visual Studio using MSBuild into a flat directory for a single configuration when I create the package, so I don't need any directories in the path for `src`.

Comment: Use nuget tokens. Typically it will look like this e.g. <file src="bin\$configuration$\MyLibrary.dll" target="lib\net461" />

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using the -IncludeReferencedProjects attribute with your nuget pack statement?

Comment: This might be better served as a comment as it does not answer the question.

Comment: I tried to add it as a comment but it said that I didn't have a high enough rep to do that?  I had this same issue and I was wanting to try and accomplish this without making a nuspec file.  I had the same issue, an assembly I wanted to create a nuget for had two other dependent assemblies.  Using `nuget pack myproject.csproj -IncludeReferencedProjects` as my command included those two dependent assemblies in my nuget package as well.  The options for the pack command can be found here [nuget pack commands](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/reference/cli-reference/cli-ref-pack)